# integrate google assistance in android application

Tags: android, bluetooth, action, google-assistant-sdk

i am Totally freshers in integrate google assistance into android app.i have task to integrate google assistance into android application.i am researching from last 3 days.i have some question need to clear first.

Here they are.

I have application that handle one machine via Bluetooth.in application there are four buttons that perform different action.Now here i have to do.

suppose i speak "Ok google,let me talk to [some invocation name]"
then it will redirect to my application and perform some action.

How can i do this ?
Help me for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once Your Assistant app is approved by Actions on Google, then your api.ai agent will be available to anyone through 'Ok google'. So, when you speak "Ok google, let me talk to [some invocation name]" then it will open up your agent. So you have to implement your api.ai agent for your machine controlling thing. 
I think you can use webhook option in the api.ai to sent control commands to a 3rd party and you have to use that 3rd party to control your machine. This 3rd party can be your android application and you can use push notification or something(use any communication method with android application) to receive commands from api.api agent and do the controlling of your machine.
And also I don't think google assistant will open up your mobile app when you say "Ok google, let me talk to [some invocation name]". Google assistant only open ups the agents that we registered in 'Actions on Google'.

You can try with **'Google Assistant SDK'**  and try to implement an android app. But still there is no android documentations or samples for that.

Also I think using [Google Assistant gRPC API](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/rpc/), you can develop some standalone google assistant solution.

Answer (score 1):

https://api.ai/

you will have to read the documenation of googles new converstion api. There you will find answers for your questions.

This is a very fresh topic since google just released the api a few days ago.

Comment: yes i did it all the thing like,create agent and then intent,Entity.and i register the action in google,But how can i access that action in my google assistance ? can you please help me ?  @Finn von Holten

Comment: https://developers.google.com/actions/samples/
have you had a look at this?

Comment: yes but there is no doc for how can i access those custom action

Comment: If I understand you right, you are having problems in integrating you assistant into your app project itself. Right? ->
You will have to use google.cloud for that. In api.ai you will have to hand over the project id of you google cloud project. Then you just have to hock you cloud project to you app.
you should have a look at this video for more detailed introductions:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SUAuy9OJg4

Comment: as per your video,Once its approved The action is made available to anyone using google assistance.Right?

Comment: So now point is can we trigger button click event with google assistance ?like when i say "ok google,talk to my [some name]" ,and than it will trigger his welcome event,after welcome event,i say "please move my bed to sleep mode" than it'll trigger the button action event.(application is installed in phone).